# How to get commandargument of button inside listview using javascript in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an asp.net application in which i have a ListView in which there is a linkbutton. i want to get commandargument of the button which is inside the listview. I have used following  code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView5" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListView5_ItemDataBound">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <li>

    <asp:Image runat="server" Style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Image") %>' />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="lblWallID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Wall_ID") %>'></asp:HiddenField>
        <p>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="linkID" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UID") %>'>
           <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Full_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
   </asp:LinkButton>
  </p>
 <p>
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Wall_Content") %>'></asp:Label>
</p>
 <p>
     <asp:Label ID="lblTime" CssClass="time-text" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TimeAgo") %>'></asp:Label>
</p>

<p>

        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Comment" OnClientClick="SaveCom(this);" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Wall_ID") %>' CommandName="Comment"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                    </p>

                                                 </li>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:ListView>
```

The Javascript function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function SaveCom() {
            var val = $(this).commandargument();
</script>
```

Comment: use `OnItemCommand="EmployeesListView_OnItemCommand"` event in code behind.

Comment: I want to get Commandargument using javascript then how can we do it.Please help me

Comment: you cant get commandargument on client because it is for server not the client. If still you want to do then you will have to parse the viewstate (very very bad idea)